# X-Ray mode not working in Solid View

Tags: 3d-view, viewlayers

Normally I can see through objects with X-Ray and Solid view enabled, like in the example picture below (This is another Blend file I opened just to check I wasn't going crazy)

[image]

However, this file wont allow me to see through the objects.

[image]

I expect this is a very easy fix and I am just being stupid, but all the other questions and answers are not helping me and even the ones that seem to be on the right track are written in such poor English I don't actually understand them

Comment: hello, maybe share the object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I'm uncomfortable sharing this project as I have put many (eeeeurgh, too many) hours into it, sorry, I know that sounds like I am being difficult and I appreciate the offer

Comment: you can share just several faces

Comment: I believe it is uploaded, friend. Thankyou

Comment: You need to include a link to it otherwise we can't download it!

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/b/oS88wwr8

Comment: Xray works fine on that file here. What Blender version are you using? - 3.2.1 here.

Comment: 3.1.2 I believe, thats what it says at the bottom right of the above pictures

Comment: Oops. Yes missed that. I was wondering because I've always had the toolbar, etc. at the top of the windows. Can't see any reason why it shouldn't work. If it's showing the same problem with all your files (including a new file), you could try resetting Blender via Fiile > Defaults > Load Factory Settings, but you'll lose any of your current startup settings.